# Access to field of child class from base class

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I don't know is it possible to do. I have two classes:

```
public class Document
    {
  public uint location;

    public Document(uint documentId)
    {
        // Here complex logic of retrieving information from DB follows
        OracleCommand documentCommand = new OracleCommand("select field1, field2, field3 from table(usr.common_pck.GetDocument(:pDocumentId))", conn);
        documentCommand.Parameters.Add("pDocumentId", documentId);
        OracleDataReader documentReader = documentCommand.ExecuteReader();
        if (documentReader.HasRows)
        {
            this.id = documentId;
            this.serial = documentReader.GetString("field2");
            this.location = Convert.ToUInt32(documentReader.GetInt32("field1"));    
            // Here I want to call "manualSetLocationStr(field3)" of DocumentViewModel
        }
    }
}
```

And here second class:

```
     public class DocumentViewModel : Document {
            private OracleConnection connection;
            private string _locationStr { get; set; }

            protected void manualSetLocationStr(string value)
            {
                _locationStr = value;
            }

            public string typeStr { get { return ((Dictionary<int, string>)HttpContext.Current.Application["DocumentTypesList"]).Single(mbox => mbox.Key == type).Value; } }

public string locationStr { 
                get {
                    if (_locationStr == null) {
                        OracleCommand getNameCommand = new OracleCommand("select usr.common_pck.GetName(:id) as name from dual", connection);
                        getNameCommand.Parameters.Add("id", this.location);
                        OracleDataReader NameReader = getNameCommand.ExecuteReader();
                        NameReader.Read();
                        _locationStr = NameReader.GetString("name");
                    }
                    return _locationStr;
                } 
            }    
        }
```

So my question is how can I call `manualSetLocationStr()` in contructor of Document? I need this to avoid second retrieving information from DB in `locationStr` get accessor, 'cause I already have it (this is `field3` in Document contructor).
Any advice, any thoughs will be very appreciated. 
Strongly hope for your help!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't the `field3` value be stored as a property of `Document`? Also, it is more standard for view models to contain an instance of their model, rather than derive from them.

**Update**

It depends on your architecture, but you could create a `DocumentInfo` type for example which has all of the properties required for your view. Then you need to populate a collection of these for your view, you can use a `DocumentInfoRepository` which provides the abstraction over the data access. This repository can either be accessed directly in your entity or from your controller, depending on the type of your domain model and the patterns you wish to employ.

Comment: `Document` class isn't for only views. It's using by another pieces of application. So I don't want to mess this entity with another things needed to render view. Actually `field3` is string representation of `field2`. So `field2` is key for `field3`. It's like `KeyValuePair`.

Comment: You will need to create a new type then specifically for the view which exposes this additional property and don't use the Document retrieval code at all.

Comment: I've updated my answer, essentially you don't want to do any data access in your view model, view models in MVC are normally simple data transfer objects (DTOs) just used to enhance the model in a way required by the view. In this case you are enhancing your model because the view needs to display a property not present on the model, but you can't do this in the view model because it is not a calculated field, but rather persisted data. Therefore, it should be retrieved in a new entity type (DocumentInfo).

Comment: Sorry, can't understand you clearly. This is a great idea about `DocumentInfo`. But could you please give me more described sample of `DocumentInfoRepository`? It will be very helpful for my newbie experience. The issue of my question is that I need to get all data for `Document` and `DocumentInfo` classes in one place which is `Document` controller. There's two instances, but info gathering process in one place. It would be very good to get one all info in one place for one DB query.

Comment: Have a look at the Storefront tutorial, it covers the repository pattern - http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/aspnet-mvc-storefront-starter-kit

Answer (score 0):

Seeing how you have OracleConnection property on a view model class - it just seems wrong. Assuming you have created the DocumentViewModel class I would strongly urge you to populate it in the controller and omit OracleCOnnection from it. Instead of inheriting from Document you can use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to map it instead. This involves 2 simple steps:

You do this once per application start:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Document, DocumentViewModel>();
```

And then use it in controller:

```
var viewModel = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Document, DocumentViewModel>(documentInstance);
```

This will create an instance of DocumentViewModel and map as many properties as it can. By doing this you get around the need to inherit from your Document class.

As for the structure of your view model. Instead of having a method typeStr, have a property TypeStr which is set after auto mapping in controller action. Same goes for your typeStr method.

The whole idea of view models is to provide UI with a dumb as possible representation of data to render. So ideally no method calls, no lazy loading (should be preloaded).

You can also use the AutoMapper to map your posted view model back to Document instance in post method, like so:

Add reverse mapping to application start:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<DocumentViewModel, Document>();
```

And in controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(DocumentViewModel viewModel)
{
    var document = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<DocumentViewModel, Document>(viewModel);
}
```

Hope this helps.

EDIT: To answer your question. You would call manualSetLocationStr() on the Document instance prior to auto mapping to view model.

Comment: Actually there's no connection field in viewmodel class. It was just for example.

Comment: What can you say about performance of AutoMapper? It would be better for me to use only native things to solve this issue, 'cause my project seems to be very big.

Comment: Could you please provide my some example on your question EDIT please? Thank you very much for your help.